# How do I run a function once when it is being called continuously

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

Pretty much, I have a joystick controlling movement of my character, it works fine for left and right being called continuously but when I try and run the function for jumping, it will continously run and keep calling the function 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtyOf.jpg
Here is an image of what the level looks like, and the joystick

I've tried have an if jumping is false

````
```THIS IS WHERE THE FUNCTION IS CALLED

if (nob.y > event.y+40) then
            jump()
            print("up")
```Function

function jump()
        if(player.isJumping ~= true ) then
                print("jumpin")
            player:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -15 *player.mass)
               player.isJumping = true
                player:setSequence("jump")
                player:play()
                print("Jumped @ ", system.getTimer())
        end
end
````

What I want to happen is for the character to jump only when it lands and not continously

Comment: I would try put `player.isJumping = true` just after if statement in `jump` function and replace condition `player.isJumping ~= true` with `not player.isJumping`. How do you detect when your character touch ground?

Comment: So i have a collision detection with the ground ,
function player.collision ( self, event )
   if( event.phase == "began" and self.isJumping ) then  
    self.isJumping = false
    self:setSequence("still")
    self:play()
    print("Landed @ ", system.getTimer())
    print("------------------------\n")
   end
  end
  player:addEventListener("collision")